# SetWindowPos outside screen

Tags: c#

I only know a little about c# and most of my code is off google. The thing I'm trying is moving a window, I got this working by using `SetWindowPos`. However, I want the window partically outside the screen, but Microsoft Windows doesn't allow it. The code below is what I got so far. Of course I searched on google for the answer, and found the answer, the only thing I don't know is how to put this into my program.

Could somebody explain me how I would put this into my application?

Google answer: [Move a window partially off the top of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645085/move-a-window-partially-off-the-top-of-the-screen)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WindowMover
{

    static class Logic
    {

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowPos")]
        public static extern IntPtr SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, int hWndInsertAfter, int x, int Y, int cx, int cy, int wFlags);

        public static void Main()
        {
            const short SWP_NOSIZE = 1;
            const short SWP_NOZORDER = 0X4;
            const int SWP_NOACTIVATE = 0x0010;

            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses("DeviceEmulator");
            foreach (var process in processes)
            {
                if (process.ProcessName == "DeviceEmulator")
                {
                    var handle = process.MainWindowHandle;
                    SetWindowPos(handle, 0, 0, 0, -100, -100, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense, you are trying to give the window a negative size.  That's of course not possible.  And then also specify SWP_NOSIZE to tell SetWindowPos() that it should not change the size.  Change the position instead.  Don't pass (0, 0), that puts it in the upper left corner of the screen, by definition not partially off the screen.

Comment: Thanks, that's at least one mystery solved!

Answer (score 0):

1. Move the constants to class scope and add `public` modifier for them.
2. Remove `Main()` from the `Logic` class
3. Save it in a `.cs` file
4. Add the file to your project.
5. Suppose your main form class was `Form1.cs`, add a line at the top

   `using WindowMover;`
6. Double click `Form1` in form designer, it would add a `Load` event handler for you and enters code editing mode
7. Call `SetWindowPos` with `this.Handle`, and latter parameters are depend on your requirement